# Defining one class for mutliple data set vs one class per data set

Tags: oop

This is not a language specific question, but a broad OOP question regarding a disagreement that I have with my team mates. But for convenience I'll use a kind of Python coding style.

Currently in our code for a specific kind of objects, there is one main class, and for each set of data an other class inheriting from the main one is defined and instantiated only once.

For example, if we would gather the list of students for all US colleges, it would be like this:

```
class College:
    _students_d = {}

    # Some methods


class Harvard(College):
    _students_d = {1: "John Doe",
                   2: "Jane Doe",
                   3: "John Wick",
                   4: "...
                   }


class MIT(College):
    _students_d = {1: "Joe Biden",
                   2: "Donald Trump",
                   3: "Barack Obama",
                   4: "...
                   }
```

I'm not an OOP expert, but from what I know about it, this is a nonsense.
To me we should have only one generic class, and then instantiate it with each data sets.
My problem is that I can't find any relevant documentation to express clearly and give weight to my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Do `MIT` and `Harvard` do things anyhow differently? For example, if they have a common method [let's say `apply_for_scolarship(student)` ] and they implement it differently - then yes! This would be polymorphism and it's one of the pillars of OOP.

On the other hand, if they don't - then I am not sure. Are you doing it only for semantics? If it is a really important concept for your application, maybe it's ok. But if they are just different ways of holding the exact same type of data, it can quickly lead to code duplication and other problems - and sometimes simple code is better.

Comment: All methods are defined in the main class, and never overridden. What do you mean by "only for semantics"?

Comment: if they use the same methods and encapsulate the same data, you can then just use the same class `mit = College(mit_students); harvard = College(harvard_students)` right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do! But my teammates disagree. And I'm looking for online resources that I could use to convince them that's the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should define a variable to represent a key, such as the name of the field for the College class, so that inheriting classes can know which school it belongs to.